# how to remove AWT label in window frame

Tags: java, awt

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {
        text += "Language : ";
        text += "Hindi: " + Hindi.getState();
        text += " English: " + English.getState();
        text += "Maths: " + Maths.getState();
        label.setText("");
        label.setText(text);
    }
```

this code show new result with previous one i want updated result only not the previous one so how can i remove previous AWT label output from the frame.

Answer (score 2):

just remove the + in the first line of the method.

```
text = "Language : ";
```

Please note that the way you are appending Strings is not efficient. Try using String.format() instead.

Comment: Or a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html).